# Jquery after browser refresh div alignment changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am zooming my application and its aligning properly using below code.
But while zoomed in and i refresh the application, the alignment goes off.

```
$('#frm-logout').each(function(){
  var inner = $(this).find('div');
  $(this).height(inner.outerHeight(true));
  $(this).width(inner.outerWidth(true)); 
});  

$('#frm-document').each(function(){
  var inner = $(this).find('div');
  $(this).height(inner.innerHeight(true));
  $(this).width(inner.outerWidth(true)); 
}); 

$('#search').each(function(){
  var inner = $(this).find('search_results');
  $(this).height(inner.outerHeight(true));
  $(this).width(inner.outerWidth(true)); 
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas?
I searched a lot but I'm stuck here.

Comment: why don't you use CSS to align your content?

Comment: how css can help while its zoomed out?

Comment: by using relative units. I honestly don't understand why exactly you would need JS here. but I also don't know the HTML structure or how it should look. ‍♂️

Comment: please share HTML structure.

Comment: @cloned - Can you please share an example to refer? I am vaguley new to this.

Comment: The question is: When do you execute the code above? Since you use it to align items, than you have to wait for page to load, so bind it to windows load event `window.onload` or in jQuery `$(window).on('load', function() { ... })`.

Comment: @skobaljic the above code is under window.on(load). issue still persists because, when i zoom in for example, the browser zoom gets to 125%, after i refresh the default page zoom is 75% but the items are zoomed to level 125% is not able adjust in default size causing alignment issues. can you please suggest any idea for this?